# Check whether a controller exists in extension of \Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment

Tags: migration, zend-framework3

I am working on a legacy application based on ZF2; some times ago we upgraded to a recent version of ZF2 and now our logs are flooded with warnings about deprecated `getServiceLocator()`.

I am searching for a way to check whether a controller exists in a router which extends `\Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment`; at the moment the source is like:

```php
    protected function isInvokableController($controller)
    {
        return $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ControllerLoader')->has($controller);
    }
```

this leads to a warning about `getServiceLocator()` deprecation.

Till now I did not find any way to get the `ControllerLoader` as DI. Is there any way to create routers via factories and getting DI (I guess there will be some other places in the application for using this) or any other way to check whether a controller exists?

Comment: You should be using the Factory Pattern, this is required by ZF2 from 2.5 onward and usage of the ServiceManager in a Controller is discouraged in the version you're at and removed from ZF3+. In the controller / service factories use the ContainerInterface (synonymous for your current ServiceManager) to get the ControllerManager (`$container->get('ControllerManager')` if memory serves me right). Make sure to start migrating those injected ServiceManager instances away from your controllers if your planning a ZF3 upgrade.

Comment: That's my problem, @rkeet – the class extends `\Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment` which has a `public static function factory($options = [])` method. This method is called by the `\Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteInvokableFactory::__invoke`. Unfortunately the `factory()` method only receives the options but no `$container`.
I tried to add a factory-method in `application.config.php` in the array `service_manager` but I could not find the correct key for this – `factories` did not work.

Comment: Have you tried registering your own Factory for your own extended-Segment implementation (register in, I think, `'service_manager' => ['factories' => [ ExtendedSegment::class => ExtendedSegmentFactory::class],],`)? If you then have a `public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, // others) { return new ExtendedSegment($container->get('ControllerManager'), $options); }` it looks like it should work. (obviously code in the Factory and `$options` has been filled) :)

Comment: Yes, I already tried this, but this does not really help – the configuration did not make it to the ServiceManager creating my class. 
After tracing done I found out that the configuration is initialized in `\Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack::init` and I saw no way on the path to the call for adding custom entries.